# Sync status notifications in Realm Mobile Platforrm

Tags: ios, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm interested in using Realm Mobile Platform in swift but I'm curious – is there an interface to determine the ongoing state of the sync? Ideally through notifications. I can't find anything like that in the docs.

Most apps would surely want to communicate to their users that the data isn't up to date yet if the app supports multiple platforms or collaboration features. I get that it's magical but sometimes you gotta show some spinners :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly something Realm plans on adding (see [#4252](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4252)), but I don't have an estimate of when that will happen yet.

Comment: Ok great, I'll keep an eye on it